# ERROR: ALTER TABLE APPEND cannot run inside a multiple commands statement

Tags: amazon-redshift, boto3, alter-table

I'm trying to iteratively pull data from MySQL and build a table in RedShift. But getting this error on `APPEND`

```
db = <some_db>
table_name = 'test'
table_name_full = f'{db}.{table_name}'
cols = ['settings', 'fields', 'design', 'confirmation']
chunk_name = 'test_1'
bucket = <some_bucket>
key = 'test.csv'
iam_role = <some_role>

query = f"""
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {chunk_name};

CREATE TABLE {chunk_name} (
    "id" integer, "{'" super, "'.join(col)}" super
    );

COPY {chunk_name} ("id", "{'", "'.join(col)}")
    FROM 's3://{bucket}/{key}'
    iam_role '{iam_role}'
    ignoreheader 1
    CSV;
    
alter table {table_name_full} append from {chunk_name};

drop table {chunk_name};
"""

session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=<some_id>,
    aws_secret_access_key=<some_key>,
    aws_session_token=<some_token>
)

config = Config(connect_timeout=180, read_timeout=180)
client_redshift = session.client("redshift-data", config=config)

result = client_redshift.execute_statement(Database=db,
                                           SecretArn=secret_arn,
                                           Sql=query,
                                           ClusterIdentifier=cluster_id)
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    stmtid = result['Id']
    response = client_redshift.describe_statement(Id=stmtid)
    print(len(response) > 1)
    print('RESPONSE: ', response)
    print('-'*100)
    time.sleep(10)
```

i tried adding `set autocommit on;` and `set autocommit off;` around the `alter`, but it just confused the compiler i guess.

Comment: Did you try adding a COMMIT; before the ALTER?

Comment: Could you try running the query directly on Redshift using a client. 
Secondly, in boto3 can you try having the `Alter table ` in a separate block and trying running it after the create and copy.

Comment: Ignore it, I tried on Redshift directly and got the same error, the only option seems to be to run it separately. You could also try reaching out to the AWS support to see why this was not documented. The weird thing is it allows any number of statements to be present after the `ALTER` but not before it in multiple statements run.

Comment: @DataWrangler so it does work if i run `alter` separately BUT if got get rid of `time.sleep(10)` it will only append and delete the chunk tables if they are small (1000 rows). I tried it with 10000 and it will create the chunk tables, but will not append or delete them. Why is that? Is there some kind of lagging happening?

Comment: I really don't see how `sleep`  would be causing the issue as the `ALTER` statement is executed before. And I really don't see any pointers in the documentation (REDSHIFT) mentioning about the dataset limit. Though I would like to understand why not use the `COPY` command to directly load the data from S3 into the target table.

Comment: @DataWrangler oh, i didn't know you can do that. How do i use COPY to load batches into the target table? Wouldn't it overwrite what's already there? And yeah, I know lol. The sleep thing is a complete mystery and i'm utterly baffled ...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, the `COPY` command that you have used is the same.. Nope it would not overwrite the data. You could try loading the data into a dummy table to play with it first. More details can be checked [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html)

Comment: @Raksha glad that made it easier for you